# Custom RoleProvider in a MultiTenant MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, multi-tenant, roleprovider

I need to develop a custom RoleProvider for a MultiTenant web app.
At the DB level, we have a table that relates Users with Roles with Tenants.

[image]

My problem is that RoleProvider gets user roles just passing the User as parameter, and we need to take the Tenant into account.

In RoleProvider implementation we have:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    //Code to retrieve roles from repo
}
```

As the roles are for a user in an specific Tenant, we need:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username, int tenantId)
{
    //Code to retrieve roles from repo
}
```

The current tenant is stored in the ControllerBase class (the one that all controllers inhereted from).

The Membership and Role Providers are in a separate project, so I don't see a way to use the current Tenant. I think I could create my custom RoleProvider in the web app project.

Any idea on how to implement the RoleProvider interface taking the Tenant as part of the input ?

Comment: A tenant is an Organization, so, for each Organization a user has a certain set of roles.

Comment: what you need is a decorator pattern basically. if the other project doesnt allow you do that, you need to wrap that within another class of yours.

Comment: @DarthVader, I don't really get what you say, I do know the decorator pattern, but since RoleProvider is "invoked" by ASP.NET MVC, I don't see how to extend it. Would you be so kind to deepen your answer?

Comment: You're sort of in a pickel. You won't be able to over ride the GetRolesForUser and add an additional parameter because the calling chain up stream won't know to use your new method. I suppose you could create your own RoleProvider and modify the initalize function as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551503/dependency-injection-and-asp-net-membership-providers and use dependency inject to inject the "tennenant" information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just to inform you what I did in my case:

As our routes are in the form of  `http://[tenantName].[domain]/[App]/[Area]` we ended up getting the `[tenantName]` from the Request, since it is unique, and with the Tenant and the `UserName` that came as a parameter I can do my select on our `UsersInTenants'` table.

The very same can be done using cookies as a way to pass aditional information.

So you can access the request, with the cookies, but for what I research the Session is not yet initialized in most cases.

Hope it helps!