# What is the benefit of using a Ninject.Factory over just injecting the IKernel?

Tags: ninject, factory

According to [this article](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/) (first paragraph), it is bad practice to inject your IKernel into wherever you need it.

Instead it is proposed to introduce a factory interface that is automatically implementend by Ninject (doing internally the same resolution).

This is an actual code snipped I am working on:

Former implementation:

```
public class CommandServer
{
    [Inject]
    public IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    ....

   public TResponse ExecuteCommand<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)
        where TResponse : ResponseBase, new()
    {
        ...
        var command = Kernel.Get<ICommand<TRequest, TResponse>>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Using a factory:

```
public class CommandServer
{
    [Inject]
    public ICommandFactory CommandFactory { get; set; }

    ....

   public TResponse ExecuteCommand<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)
        where TResponse : ResponseBase, new()
    {
        ...
        var command = CommandFactory.CreateCommand<TRequest, TResponse>();
        ...
    }
}

// at binding time:
public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand<TRequest, TResponse> CreateCommand<TRequest, TResponse>();
}

Bind<ICommandFactory>().ToFactory();
```

I am not saying I don't like it (it looks nice and clean) - just not exactly sure why the former is particularly bad and the latter is so much better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should not be using the Service Locator pattern. Why you ask? Please see [Mark Seeman](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)(comments, too!) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-anti-pattern). Using the `IKernel` (or somewhat better: only the `IResolutionRoot` part of it) smells *like* Service Locator.

Now Mark would suggest that you should apply the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) instead - and he also mentions the Dynamic proxy approach.

I personally think that using ninject auto-generated factories (= dynamic proxy approach) instead is worth the trade off.
You should **not** use a factory like:

```
public interface IServiceLocator
{
    T Create<T>();
}
```

because well.. it's service locator ;-)

However, using something like

```
public interface IResponseHandleFactory
{
    IResponseHandle Create(int responseId);
}
```

is perfectly fine.

Of course you can also do this by using the `IResolutionRoot` directly - instead of the factory. The code would look like:

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IResponseHandle>(
    new ConstructorArgument("responseId", theResponseIdValue);
```

### Reasons not to use `IResolutionRoot` directly

- A lot of the `IResolutionRoot` "methods" are in fact extension methods. That complicates unit-testing **a lot** (it's basically not a sensible choice if you want to unit test it, at all).
- *slight* worse decoupling from container (=> ease of changing DI containers) than when using a factory interface. The auto-generated factory feature you can also implement as an add on to other containers - if they don't have it already (i've done so personally for Unity and AutoFac). However it requires some know-how about dynamic proxies.

Alternative to factory interfaces: Using `Func<>` factories. The above example could also be replaced by `Func<int, IResponseHandle>()`. Quite a lot DI containers support this out of the box / with standard plugins (ninject needs the Factory extension). So you'd be decoupled from the container even more. Disadvantage: harder to unit test and not clearly named parameters.

Comment: What is the best way you recommend then? When using `IResponseHandle Create(int responseId);` there needs to be an instantiation at some point also?

Comment: @Ozkan The implementation for this can be done "automagically" in a tried & tested way: [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory). An alternative is to write the implementation of `IResponseHandleFactory` manually (note: do make it part of the composition root! - also see Mark Seeman's blgo posts on the topic)