# Dependency injection container is not supplying contextAccessor parameter to constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

## Initial Question

I'm calling this `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>()` and am receiving the following error. Why doesn't the dependency inject take care of supplying a non-null `contextAccessor`?

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contextAccessor
  ParamName=contextAccessor
  Source=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager`1..ctor(UserManager`1 userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1 claimsFactory, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor, ILogger`1 logger)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at ResourceOwnerPasswordFlow.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Configure>b__1(OpenIdConnectServerOptions options) in C:\Users\BigFont\Documents\GitHub\AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server\samples\ResourceOwnerPasswordFlow\Startup.cs:line 109
       at Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.ConfigureOptions`1.Configure(TOptions options, String name)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IUrlEncoder encoder, ConfigureOptions`1 configureOptions)
       at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IDistributedCache cache, IHtmlEncoder htmlEncoder, IUrlEncoder urlEncoder, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, IOptions`1 options, ConfigureOptions`1 configuration) in C:\Users\BigFont\Documents\GitHub\AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server\src\AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server\OpenIdConnectServerMiddleware.cs:line 38
  InnerException:
```

## Research

I've seen the constructor injection done in the sample project [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/cf132e1057fb01dca269333f70a70847e9086cee/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/ManageController.cs#L15-L19) and it just works. What am I missing?

```
public ManageController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}
```

I've also seen in the [Music Store Tests](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/08274056a123e63ac49bd8241ca76621995c54fd/test/MusicStore.Test/ManageControllerTest.cs#L32-L37) the explicit addition of an `HttpContextAccessor` into the service collection. Do I need to do this also? How come?

```
// IHttpContextAccessor is required for SignInManager, and UserManager
services.AddInstance<IHttpContextAccessor>(
    new HttpContextAccessor()
        {
            HttpContext = new TestHttpContext(),
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

> serviceProvider.GetRequiredService< SignInManager< IdentityUser>>()

So it looks like you are using service locator anti pattern which is ok if you must but it seems like you are requesting the wrong type
shouldn't you be using:

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService< SignInManager< ApplicationUser>>()
```

Since that is the type that is being injected into `ManageController` and you know already that the DI can resolve it?

I can tell you that in my own code I'm using constructor injection and one of my classes takes `IHttpContextAccessor` in its constructor and it gets injected just fine without me having to register that type with the service collection so I think it gets added elsewhere from Microsoft code since they also depend on it in identity classes

I don't think you should add an instance of `HttpContext` to services collection. If you need to access `HttpContext` then you should declare a constructor dependency if possible on `IHttpContextAccessor` which will then enable you to access the current `HttpContext`

For example in my code I have a constructor like this:

```
public RequestSiteResolver(
        ISiteRepository siteRepository,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        contextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        siteRepo = siteRepository;
        config = configuration;

    }
```

and `IHttpContextAccessor` does get injected without me having to explicitly add it to the service container. Then I can use it later to access the current `httpContext` like so:

```
string host = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
```

Comment: In my own code, I'm using `IdentityUser` instead of extending it with something like `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: The `ManageController` isn't from my code; rather, it's from an example of code from the docs.

Comment: I'm not sure that the service locator is an anti-pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-anti-pattern It just seems like something we ought to use thoughtfully.