# Is it ok to use IKernel in Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an MVC Controller with many different Actions. I use `Ninject` for dependency injection.

Each action requires some specific dependencies.

How is it better to inject these dependencies?

1. Inject all of them in the Controller, and use the ones i need.
2. Inject only `IKernel` in Controller, and get the dependencies in the current action which is executed.

I think that approach #2 is better, because i can avoid creating some dependencies that will not be used.

Example 1:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService1 _service1;
    private readonly IService2 _service2;
    private readonly IService3 _service3;
    public MyController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, IService3 service3)
    {
        _service1 = service1;
        _service2 = service2;
        _service3 = service3;
    }

    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        _service1.Get();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        _service2.Get();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Action3()
    {
        _service3.Get();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    public MyController(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        IService1 _service1 = _kernel.Get<IService1>();
        _service1.Get();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        IService2 _service2 = _kernel.Get<IService2>();
        _service2.Get();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Action3()
    {
        IService3 _service3 = _kernel.Get<IService3>();
        _service3.Get();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Service locator is anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Never inject the container anywhere except for [infrastructure components](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/). That means Controllers are a no-go. Sure, it may be easier to make controllers this way, but you more than pay the price in maintenance when you need to figure out what a controller depends on.

Comment: I know using a Service locator is bad, especially because you can be tempted to send only the Service locator as a dependency for all your Services. The only exception i can think about would be at the application entry point, which in this case would only be the Controllers

Comment: The Controllers are _not_ in the application's entry point. Controllers live in your UI layer, which is a different layer than your application's entry point. You can find a more thorough explanation about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9505530/264697).

Comment: Note that if your controllers have a large set of dependencies, where each action has its own _set_ of dependencies that is not used by other actions, it means that the methods in the controller have _low cohesion_ and this is an indication of a **Single Responsibility Principle** violation. In that case it might be better to split your Controller into multiple smaller controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, example #2 is ***Service Locator Pattern***. Many of us used it in ASP.Net Web Form in good old days - we didn't know any better back then.

However, better alternatives exists for ASP.Net MVC such as Constructor Injection - a default goal for DI - example #1.

Service Locator has few problems. One of them is it doesn't follow ***Don't call us, we'll call you*** principle. Instead, we directly ask for the things we need rather than handed them to us.

With the service locator, we have to examine the code, searching for capricious calls that retrieve a required service. Constructor injection allowed us to view
dependencies—all of them—with a glance at the constructor, or at a distance, via IntelliSense.

*Source: [Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) and [Adaptive Code via C# by Gary McLean Hall](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735683204)*

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is using `Ninject`'s `IKernel` as a Service Locator, which defined by Mark Seemann is an anti-pattern ([source](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/))

> Service Locator is a well-known pattern, and since it was described by Martin Fowler, it must be good, right?
>
> No, it's actually an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

He explains with details and examples why `Service Locator` is an anti-patern, eg.

> - API usage issues
> - Maintenance issues

---

You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-an-anti-pattern) question for more info