# What makes a ServiceLocator be an anti-pattern?

Tags: c#, anti-patterns, service-locator

I am struggling on what makes the ServiceLocator an anti-pattern.

Some say, that passing the container around qualifies it as an antipattern, others fear the maintainability once the app grows (hidden dependencies).
The following sample demonstrates a simple registration with AutoFac including dependencies:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutoFacSample
{
    using System.Reflection;
    using Autofac;    

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).Where(t => t.Name.Contains("First")).AsImplementedInterfaces();            
            Holder.Container = builder.Build();
            var first = Holder.Container.Resolve<IFirst>();
        }
    }

   public static class Holder
    {
        public static IContainer Container { get; set; }
    }

   public interface IFirst {}

   public interface ISecond {}

   public interface IThird {}

   public class First : IFirst
    {
        public First(ISecond second)
        {        
        }
    }

   public class Second : ISecond
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            var third = Holder.Container.Resolve<IThird>();            
        }
    }

    public class Third : IThird {}    

}
```

Would you consider my sample as an anti-pattern? If so, is there any good alternative?

**EDIT:**
I'm aware of the question [Is ServiceLocator an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-an-anti-pattern) but the answer doesn't explain weather my sample is an anti-pattern or not.

Thanks,

Trini

Comment: It just hides dependencies. For `First` it's immediately clear it depends on `ISecond` (because you pass it in constuctor). For `Second` you have no idea it depends on `IThird` unless you have access to source code.

Comment: You can read `Dependency Injection in Net` from Seemann.

Comment: This anti-pattern also limits composability. What if you want to have two instances of `Second` and have each one of them talking to a different implementation of `IThird`? See this article for more details: http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/10/25/object-composability-another-reason-why-the-service-locator-is-an-anti-pattern/

Comment: The alternative is to declare `IThird` in the constructor of `Second`, i.e., use constructor injection.

Comment: I already read Seemann's blog post (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)
which only tells me, that its bad using the servicelocator as it makes maintainability harder and the overall API usage.