# Log Exceptions with EntityFramework in WebAPI Exception Filter or IExceptionLogger

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I'm thinking to use `ExceptionLogger` or `ExceptionFilterAttribute` in my `Web API 2.x` application. My OR/M is `Entity Framework 6` and `AutoFac` as my `IoC`.

Consider exception attribute below:

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    public IDbContext MyContext { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);

        // some code

        MyContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I think, if my app throws any exception `OnException` method will be invoke and I need a new instance of `DbContext` to save the error log, but my `AutoFac` configuration for `DbContext` is `InstancePerRequest` so I think `AutoFac` will resolve `MyContext` as a shared `DbContext`.

Here is my `AutoFac` configuration for `DbContext`:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>()
       .As<IDbContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

How could I make `AutoFac` to reslove `DbContext` as a new instance for `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since no one answered my question, I talk a little about how everyone could solve this problem. To solve this problem you can only use `ServiceLocator` pattern ([it's an anti-pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-an-anti-pattern)). By injecting a life-time-scope object of AutoFac you are able to create different scopes.

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    // public IDbContext MyContext { get; set; }
    public readonly ILifetimeScope LifeTimeScpoe{ get; set; }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);

        // some code
        using(var scope = LifeTimeScope.BeginLifeTimeScope("ExceptionLogging"))
        {
           using(var dbContext = scope.Resolve<>(IDbContext))
           {
              // do some log logic
              dbContext.SaveChanges();
           }
        }
    }
}
```