# How to request vector<T> as a template type argument

Tags: c++, c++17

In general, how would you request `vector<T>` as a type in a template?

```
template<?vector<T>?>
void allocate() {
  vector<T> vector;
}
```

To be more specific (the example above is a bit dumb), I'm using a `service_locator<T>` from [this](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) library and all of its members are static. The constructor and the destructor of that struct are deleted, therefore there is no such thing as an instance of a `service_locator<T>`. I'd like to write a function that does something, given some `service_locator<T>`. Something like the following.

```
template<?service_locator<T>?> // What do I write here?
T& assertedRef() {
  assert(!service_locator<T>::empty(), "Value not initialized for that type!");
  return service_locator<T>::ref();
}
```

My current workaround is to ask for `T` instead of `service_locator<T>`. This is a hassle for the callers because it's on them to figure out the underlying type the `service_locator` is operating on (most of them are aliased to something more readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partial specialization for this. Since that's not supported for functions, you have to forward the call to a partially specialized class instance.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct AssertedRefFunctor {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1, "Not a service locator");
};

template <typename T>
struct AssertedRefFunctor<entt::service_locator<T>> {
    T& operator()() {
        if (entt::service_locator<T>::empty()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Value not initialized for that type!");
        }
        return entt::service_locator<T>::ref();
    }
};

template <typename T>
auto assertedRef() -> decltype(std::declval<AssertedRefFunctor<T>>()()) {
    return AssertedRefFunctor<T>{}();
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
assertedRef<entt::service_locator<int>>();
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/f-oUpY

Answer (score 1):

C++ (at least C++17) does not support template parameter constraints like C# does (they were proposed for C++0x as "concepts" but withdrawn). But you *can* have a static assert using [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

And as a hint to whoever consumes your library, I'd name the template parameter as `TVector` and `TVectorItem` to be clear that it expects a `vector<TVectorItem>` derivative.

(And I agree with the (now deleted) comment [that the Service Locator pattern is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-an-anti-pattern). There are almost always better alternatives to using the Service Locator pattern - but we'd need to know more about your application before suggesting anything).

(And if you're using Visual Studio or MSBuild and want to build a statically-evaluated or `constexpr` DI container builder, consider using T4 for codegen instead of C++ templates).

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TVector, typename TVectorItem>
void allocate() {

    static_assert( std::is_base_of<vector<TVectorItem>, TVector>::value, "TVector must derive from vector<TVectorItem>." );

    TVector vector;
}
```

Comment: If the caller needs to provide TVectorItem then the workaround in the question seems better.

Comment: The service locator is providing repositories (resource loader), audio service, and a physics world (for now). Instances that live as long as the program itself. The service locator is currently used in header/cpp files with free functions where I'm doing construction and manual dependency injection (passing instances through the constructor myself). -- it's a personal hobby project

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct way to do that.

In your case, you might do:

```
template <typename ServiceLocatorT>
auto assertedRef() -> decltype(ServiceLocatorT::ref())
{
  assert(!ServiceLocatorT::empty(), "Value not initialized for that type!");
  return ServiceLocatorT::ref();
}
```

In generic case, template classes might have aliases of there template (as done with STL `std::vector<T>::value_type`) that you can use.

At worst, you might create type_traits:

```
template <typename T> struct value_type;

template <typename T> struct value_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};
// ...
```