Is using IServiceProvider impactful with base controller in .NET
Is it good practice to pass service provider to our controller ?
Method No 1 :
[Authorize]
public abstract partial class BaseSecureController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    protected readonly ISender _sender;
    protected readonly Guid? _userId;

    public BaseSecureController(IServiceProvider ServiceProvider) 
    {
        _serviceProvider = ServiceProvider;

        _sender = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISender>();

        _userId = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserContext>().UserId();

        GeneralGuards.AgainstNullUserId(_userId);
    }
}

In this approach we could add cached dictionary and then retrieve the services from it
Method No 2:
[Authorize]
public abstract partial class BaseSecureController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ISender _sender;
    protected readonly Guid? _userId;

    public BaseSecureController(ISender sender, IUserContext userContext) 
    {
        _sender = sender;
        _userId = userContext?.UserId();

        GeneralGuards.AgainstNullUserId(_userId);
    }
}

In this approach, we will pass the injection from the controller that is inheriting this controller.
I want to know which approach is better with unit testing POV, good practice and performance wise in the long term.
IServiceProvider contains all services, so as the number of services increases will it impact the performance of the first approach?

Method 2 allows for direct mocking of dependencies, simplifying testing. It also adheres better to SOLID principles and has a performance improvement by resolving dependencies once through the DI container.

2 is the better approach.
Directly using IServiceProvider is regarded as something of an anti-pattern. The code consuming the services is better when it does not know how it is provided with those services: better separation of concerns.
As the first comment on the question notes it also makes testing easier (less to double as a mock service provider is not needed).

IServiceProvider contains all services, so as the number of services increases will it impact the performance of the first approach?

In the second approach the code that instantiates the controller gets the services needed to instantiate the controller from the service provider anyway, so the lookups into the provider will be the same. And framework code, as it is heavily used, gets a lot of performance attention that most business logic code cannot justify.

"Directly using IServiceProvider is regarded as something of an anti-pattern." @Richard is referring to the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Here's a better link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22795888/67392 (and covers why this is not, IMHO, an anti-pattern; but rather is sometimes an anti-pattern).

Unfortunately, the reasoning in that answer is flawed, because a Service Locator is defined by its role, not by its mechanics—or at least, when you follow DIPP&P's definition. This means that a DI Container, when used outside the Composition Root, is following the Service Locator pattern while, when called inside the Composition Root, is merely an infrastructure component.

@Steven I think we need to agree to disagree. If only because IME being too focused on precise definitions and roles is just a route to architectural astronautics; instead be focused on solving the business problem at hand in an efficient and maintainable. (Of course if the business problem is selling books/getting page hits on these 6topics you've got another problem).

I hope you're not accusing me of trying to sell books, because the main thing I want to do is share my knowledge. But I can absolutely agree to disagree here. We clearly approaching this from different angles with different experiences. That's fine.

No, the author of those articles you link to.

Well, I'm the coauthor of the book DIPP&P, and all the links I provided are mine and that of the other author: Mark Seemann.
